# Why does Jenkins pop up in my browser insted of Ambari?

Tags: jenkins, networking, virtual-machine, portforwarding

I am running HDP-sandbox on VM VirtulBox(host is Ubuntu). From localhost:1080

[image]

I choose Ambari,broser redirects to 8080. But to my great surprise

[image]

How to find out where is Jenkins process and disable it?

ps

```
 ps aux | grep jenkins
jenkins   3132  0.0  0.0  77020  6808 ?        Ss   08:37   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
jenkins   3135  0.0  0.0 114676  2688 ?        S    08:37   0:00 (sd-pam)
jenkins   3151  0.0  0.0  29040   180 ?        S    08:37   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
jenkins   3154  0.3  2.1 7973532 357496 ?      Sl   08:37   0:21 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
miki     13760  0.0  0.0  23080  1012 pts/0    R+   10:11   0:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

Netstat host output

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3154/java
```

HDP netstat

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# netstat -plnt | grep ':8080'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      367/java
```

I checked port-forwarding on my VM

[image]

Virtual adapter is attached to real network with NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can view the password and use it on the GUI prompt?
`sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

You can disable jenkins by `systemctl disable jenkins`

Comment: Works after the restart.